# Why didn't Doctor Strange check this before he created a portal to Norway?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-ragnarok

In *Thor: Ragnarok* movie, Doctor Strange consulted a book to check if the portal spell required any Asgardian modification. Why didn't he also check for Jotun modification as Loki is actually a frost giant from Jotunheim, not Asgardian?

Comment: May be subordinated to the more relevant question, "Was Dr. Strange Just Screwing With Thor When He 'Prepared' For The Spell?"

Comment: Well... he'd *prepared* to deal with Loki... and had in fact done so.

Comment: But how did Odin get to the Norway? Or did Dr. Strange just, visited him there.

Comment: @Oni Airplanes. Ships.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [script](https://waltdisneystudiosawards.com/media/scripts/thor_ragnarok.pdf) (and movie) show that he was only studying the book of magic for a few seconds. One assumes that it simply said that it works for *everyone*, regardless of their planet of origin.

> [Strange stands up and suddenly they are standing by a bookcase.
>   Strange takes down an ancient book, **flips through it.**]
>
> **STRANGE:** *I’m just seeing whether this incantation requires any Asgardian modifications.*
>
> [Thor reaches out to the bookcase to steady himself.]
>
> **STRANGE (CONT’D):** *Nope.*

Additionally, it's not clear whether Doctor Strange (a human from Earth) would have been aware that Loki isn't a full Asgardian. Although it's common knowledge to us, the audience, this factoid may have passed Strange by.